# Handle base64 file content into something viewable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, base64, blob, filereader

I'm just stuck for a while due to my lack of knowledge in some, I guess, basic fields. I've an app written in vue.js and have an external service, which at some point send me a base64 string representing a pdf/img/txt document (whatever). What I try to do is displaying content of this document to my user but can't figure out how to do. What I achieve for now is the obtention of an url.

```
async downloadPdf() {
    let res = await this.$store.dispatch('pdf/getBase64String')
    let base64String = res.status === 'ok' ? res.data : ''
    this.downloadUrl = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64String
    // downloadUrl bind href on a button in my page
}
```

Once I set the href value with this downloadUrl variable Chrome opens me a new tab but remains blank and in infinite loading.
I guess it's not the good way. I also tried with `new Blob`, `new FileReader` and so on, without success.
So I'm looking for the right way to handle such a thing : viewing document content from its base64 string

Answer (score 0):

Try download it:

```
async downloadPdf() {
    let res = await this.$store.dispatch('pdf/getBase64String')
    let base64String = res.status === 'ok' ? res.data : ''
    this.downloadUrl = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64String
    // downloadUrl bind href on a button in my page
    open(this.downloadUrl);
    // or, if it is not encode
    open(btoa(this.downloadUrl));
}
```